# How to fire an event when Cookies has just expired in GWT?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, here is the requirement.

I want to build a system look like this:

```
- Header: have a PleaseLoginPanel and SuccessfulLoginPanel
- Content Page just contains content & communicate with header via EventBuss
- HeaderPresenter is the parent presenter & ContentPresenter is nested inside the Header presenter.
```

Let say when user opens this url "`mydomain#content`" they will see a page that has header contaning `PleaseLoginPanel` on top & a content part (beneath the header) contaning some `textarea` and `button` for user to input data and submit to DB .

To be able to access the widget in content page the user need to login, after logged in, the  `PleaseLoginPanel` will be invisible and the `SuccessfulLoginPanel` will be visible. User now can play with widgets in content part.

Let say `Session & Cookies` will last 1 hour, after the session  cookies expired the user can not submit the content data.

Let say user spent a lot of efforts to prepare data & about to submit but the session expired so he can't submit. At that time, in the header the `SuccessfulLoginPanel` still stay there. So the user can lose all his content he prepared before. You may say, he can open a new page & login & copy the data from the old page (the page that has session expired & does not have `PleaseLoginPanel`), but that still cost him a lot of effort to copy over.

So I want that, when the Cookes has just expired it will fire an Event to the Header & ask the header to show the `PleaseLoginPanel`

How can we do that in GWT or GWTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that is to use timer

```
    Timer showLoginPanelTimer = new Timer() {
          public void run() {

              getView().getLoginPanel().setVisible(true);
              getView().getSuccessfulLoginPanel().setVisible(false);
              getView().getEmailBox().setText("");
              getView().getPasswordBox().setText("");
              Utility.removeUserInfoCookies();
          }
     };


    showLoginPanelTimer.schedule(Utility.COOKIE_TIMEOUT);
```